# What's the meaning of the German word »ran«?

Tags: vocabulary

The three below paragraphs come from the article in *Der Spiegel* called  “[Deutschland 2017. Drei Wirtschaftsrätsel für Aschenbrödel](http://www.spiegel.de/wirtschaft/soziales/deutschland-2017-drei-wirtschaftsraetsel-fuer-aschenbroedel-kolumne-a-1184588.html)”. My question refers to the first sentence of the THIRD paragraph. What's the meaning of the German word *ran* there? (I'm quoting the first two paragraphs for context purposes.)

> Was für ein komisches Fest. Deutschlands Wirtschaft wächst mit mehr als zwei Prozent so stark wie zuletzt vor vielen Jahren. Die Unternehmen melden Auftragsrekorde. Die Deutschen geben erstmals wieder deutlich mehr Geld aus. Und es wurden netto mehr als 600.000 vollwertige Jobs im Land geschaffen - Zehnjahresrekord. Die Arbeitslosenquote nähert sich immer neuen Rekordtiefs. Das eine oder andere Land zieht gerade wahrscheinlich in Erwägung, mit uns zu tauschen.
>
> Und was machen die Deutschen? Wählen statt Frau Ich-mach-das-schon-Merkel übellaunig alle möglichen Grüppchen, die jetzt entweder nicht regieren wollen oder es nicht können.
>
> *Jetzt sollen die Ollen wieder **ran**, von denen wiederum die einen eigentlich versprochen hatten, gar nicht mehr zu regieren - und die auch keiner so richtig will.* Deutschland 2017. Rätselhaft - und mit hohem Störpotenzial für die Familienzusammenkunft am Heiligen Abend, jenem traditionsreichen Moment für ritualisierte politische Bekundungen. Irgendwann kommt die Rede ja doch immer auf die Lage im Land.

In [dict.cc](https://de-en.dict.cc/?s=ran), there are some usage examples of *ran*, but I don't find them helpful in understanding the word's meaning in the paragraph above.

Comment: "Now it is up to the old ones (the previous ones) again."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Ran" is normally the colloquial version of ["heran"](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/heran). In this case, however, "X soll(en) heran" needs to be read as a phrase that means "it is X's job; X is expected to take care of it". (Note the difference between "ran" (from "heran") and "dran". E.g. "jetzt bist du dran" means, "Now it's your turn." And "du musst ran" means "that is your job" or "you should take care of that".)

"Die Ollen" is colloquial for "Die Alten"; in this context it refers to those who were already in the previous government. In other words, according to the author, the Germans will get the same government as before the 2017 elections, even though the Social Democrats ("die einen") had promised not to govern.

Duden lists [ranmüssen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ranmuessen) as a shortened version of [heranmüssen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/heranmuessen). Both verbs are colloquial. The second meaning "eine Arbeit, Aufgabe übernehmen müssen". Duden also lists [heransollen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/heransollen), meaning "herankommen, -fahren, -gehen o. Ä. sollen".

Comment: There is a small difference between *ran* and *dran* and there is also a subtle difference between "Du bist dran" ('It's your turn") and "Du musst ran" ("It's your job"), the latter often implying that no other can do the job.

Comment: @RHa Stimmt; danke. Ich habe das jetzt ein bisschen ausführlicher erklärt.

Comment: I would say that "heranmüssen" is short for "herangehen müssen", where "herangehen" is more or less "to take up a task". In other words "du musst ran" means something like "you should take up the task -- it is up to you"